# mysql.data.entity.mysqlconnectionfactory.createconnection(System.String): overriding method must match the security accessibility

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, blend

I have a visual c# project using mysql.data & mysql.data.entities (from NuGet) for mysql connectivity.

But for some reason, this breaks data binding in blend with the following error:
"mysql.data.entity.mysqlconnectionfactory.createconnection(System.String)"
"overriding method must match the security accessibility"

error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6fcy.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it after a while is by installing mysql.data only (so remove the mysql.data.entities package that's causing issues). so far everything still works & edge doesn't make an issue anymore.